# Incorrect datetime value para un campo fecha

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando hacer una conversión de fecha para añadir un valor en un campo que tiene el siguiente formato:

```
time DATETIME,
```

El error que me aparece es el siguiente:

```
MariaDB [RPI02]> INSERT INTO RPI02 (`time`,`cpu`,`gpu`) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('180320194735','%d%m%Y%H%i%s'),'35.780','36.9');
ERROR 1411 (HY000): Incorrect datetime value: '180320194735' for function str_to_date
```

Que estoy poniendo mal para que no me deje añadir la fecha en formato **180320194735** ?

Gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que se cae justo al aplicarle la hora, y mysql no considera `47` como hora ni los relojes llegan a eso, así que para hacer que mysql te convierta un `string` en formato `DATE` ([tutorial](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/)) tienes que seguir este formato:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('18032019040735','%d%m%Y%H%i%s');
```

Así que tu consulta tendría que ser así:

```
INSERT INTO RPI02 (`time`,`cpu`,`gpu`) VALUES
(STR_TO_DATE('18032019040735','%d%m%Y%H%i%s'),'35.780','36.9');
```

Comment: muchas gracias!!